# How to SUM parts of a column which have same text value in different column in the same row

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sum, pivot-table

I have a column with names and a column with numbers:

```
FirstName    Name    Number
John         Smith     17
John         Smith     26
Peter        Smith     116
Peter        Smith     25
Franck       Black     17
Luke        Peterson   17
Luke        Peterson   37
```

Names with same `FirstName` and `Name` represent the same person. I need to sum the numbers associated with them. I prefer not to use VBA.

Answer (score 13):

A PivotTable might suit, though I am not quite certain of the layout of your data:

[image: SO19669814 example]

The bold numbers (one of each pair of duplicates) need not be shown as the field does not have to be subtotalled eg:

[image: SO19669814 second example]

Answer (score 12):

This can be done by using `SUMPRODUCT` as well. Update the ranges as you see fit

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=A2)*($B$2:$B$7=B2)*$C$2:$C$7)
```

A2:A7 = First name range

B2:B7 = Last Name Range

C2:C7 = Numbers Range

This will find all the names with the same first and last name and sum the numbers in your numbers column

Comment: Very much so, thanks. While I'm here again, I'll change it to a 'normal' formula using `SUMPRODUCT` instead of an array formula using `SUM`.

Answer (score 6):

If your data has the names grouped as shown then you can use this formula in D2 copied down to get a total against the last entry for each name

`=IF((A2=A3)*(B2=B3),"",SUM(C$2:C2)-SUM(D$1:D1))`

See screenshot

[image]